# query convert from sql to linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I want to convert following SQL query to LINQ

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   campaign_newslettersubscriber_track a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT campaignid, 
                                   Min(id) AS id 
                   FROM   campaign_newslettersubscriber_track 
                   GROUP  BY campaignid) AS b 
               ON a.campaignid = b.campaignid 
                  AND a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL?
C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var subquery = from c in objectContext.campaign_newslettersubscriber_track 
                         group c by c.campaignid into g
                         select new
                         {
                             id = g.Min(x => x.campaignid),
                             campaignId = g.Key
                         };

var n = from c in objectContext.campaign_newslettersubscriber_track 
        join cin in subquery.Distinct() on c.campaignid equals cin.campaignId
        select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the tool called [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/).

It can take T-SQL and convert it to LINQ, LINQ to SQL (using `SqlMetal`) or LINQ to Entities (using `EdmGen`).

Be advised that this is not a free tool ($60.00 for one license, cheaper for more, at the time of this writing) and will not convert all T-SQL functions, here is the list of supported [functions](http://www.sqltolinq.com/functions).